# is it possible to integrate payment getway in PYQT5 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, payment-gateway

i need to integrate UPI payment getway in my Desktop Application . any idea how we can do the integration of UPI and PAYTM?

Comment: Please clearify your question, e.g. do you want to add "pay now" button on PyQT GUI app?

Comment: yes im building vending machine. i want to pay after button click. do you have any solution @HotteShen

Comment: Which payment gateway service are you targeting? Adding "pay now!" button for only PayPal is not so hard.

Comment: but what is method to integrate @HotteShen

Comment: i dont know the exact method i just need suggestion for method

Comment: Use PayPal's "Buy Now!" button embed code on WebView.